# Unable to scrape the next page(pagination) using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, pagination

I tried to scrape data from konga.com. But I was able to scrape the first page but the 2nd page was giving problem. I also copied the URL of the PAGE 2 of the site but it does work. 
the code is here below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')

for i in range(1,50):
   y= '%0d'%i
   url="https://www.konga.com/category/electronics-5261?"+ "page="+'%0d'%i
   print url
   browser.get("url")


p=browser.find_elements_by_xpath ("//div[@class='af885_1iPzH']/h3")

for a in p:
        print '.........page'+ str(i)+ '..........' 
        print a.text
```

Comment: What are you trying to scrap excatly?

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Python27\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')

for i in range(1,50):
   y= '%0d'%i
   url="https://www.konga.com/category/electronics-5261?"+ "page="+'%0d'%i
   print url
   browser.get("url")

p=browser.find_elements_by_xpath ("//div[@class='af885_1iPzH']/h3")

#q=browser.find_elements_by_xpath ("//div[@class='_4e81a_39Ehs']/ span[@class='d7c0f_sJAqi']")
for i in p:
        print '.........page'+ str(i)+ '..........' 
        print i.text

Comment: I meant the element on your page. I got the script to work but I am not sure what you are looking for on the page.

Comment: I am trying to scrape the name of the of the product listed

Comment: this is the  error I got:

Comment: You should include the error in the original question also

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  And--per @Edeki Okoh indicates--don't post code in comments (instead, edit the original question).

Comment: do you only want the product names?

Answer (score 1):

You were close. The issue is you were trying to find the class name before it was actually loaded onto the page. Same thing with the pagination links. It looks like those elements are not fully loaded in for a few seconds until after the page is loaded. What you need to do is have your webdriver wait a few seconds until that element is visible using the [WebDriverWait](https://www.google.com/search?q=webdriverwait&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS835US835&oq=WebDriverWait&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.646j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) method:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")  # fatal


page = 0

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\edekio\Downloads\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)

url = "https://www.konga.com/category/electronics-5261"
browser.get(url)

while page < 51:

    page = page + 1


    next_page = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, str(page))))
    next_page.click()


    print("page " + str(page))

    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "af885_1iPzH")))
    print(element.text)
```

Output for first 3 pages:

```
page 1
Q18 Smartwatch - Silver
page 2
Zealot S12 Bluetooth Wireless Speaker...
page 3
I8 Tws Wireless Earbuds - White
```

This was written in python 3.6. It looks like you are using python 2.x but you can use an online converter if it doesn't work for your version. I would recommend upgrading to python 3.6 for Selenium since I do not know if all of their features work on Python 2.x

Comment: Thank you for the script. But I want the whole products for each page